# Javascript function returns undefined as it should not be

Tags: javascript, jquery, email-validation

I have function check dynamic input fields with a certain class. Those fields takes email address so checking if it is a valid email address.

There could be many email field, if one of them fails against email address test, it should return `FALSE`, else it should return `TRUE`. Finally when submit clicked `save_form()` runs. If it get `false`, it should stop, otherwise continue. But it gets "undefined" always.

Here is what I have:

```
function validate_email_string(email_address) {
  var emailReg=/^([\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/;
  var emailTest = emailReg.test(email_address);
  var result = (emailTest === false) ? false : true;
  return result;
}

function validate_email_extensions(email_field_selector, message) {
  var invalid_message = null;
  if (typeof message !== "undefined") {
    invalid_message = message;
  } else {
    invalid_message = '<?=lang("i18n_invalid_email_address");?>';
  }
  var email_fields_length = $(email_field_selector).length;
  var is_valid = true;
  if (email_fields_length) {
    $(email_field_selector).each(function(index, el) {
      if($(el).val()) {
        if(!validate_email_string($(el).val())) {
          is_valid = false;
        }
        if (index === email_fields_length - 1) {
          if (is_valid === false) {
            Interact.show(invalid_message);
          }
          return is_valid;
        }
      } else {
        if (index === email_fields_length - 1) {
          if (is_valid === false) {
            Interact.show(invalid_message);
          }
          return is_valid;
        }
      }
    });
  } else {
    return is_valid;
  }
}

function save_form() {
    var emails = validate_email_extensions('.jq-extension-email');
    if(!emails){return false}
    ....
```

But `validate_email_extensions` function returns undefined. I put `console.log()` everywhere, probably it's blind of me but any help is quite appreciated.

Comment: @Hanky Panky First `if` is not supposed to return anything :) It is just for setting a default message. Thanks for contribution anyway.

Comment: Yeah i didnt mention correctly which first then i realized that can be ambiguous so i removed the comment and put it in an answer with different content

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your returns are from your loop to `validate_email_extensions`, not from `validate_email_extensions` to `save_form` as you're expecting.

`validate_email_extensions` needs to return the value to `save_form` still.

The only time where your function is correctly returning a value is when this case is `FALSE`

```
if (email_fields_length) {
```

It returns no value when control goes in that `if` condition.

Comment: `is_valid` defined before this statement. So the idea is to set `is_valid` as `true` by default. During each loop, set it `false` if validation fails. And after the last loop, check if `ìs_valid` is `false`. If it is, it means at least one field is failed from validation. So I think it must be ok when you notice the rest of the code. Though, If I'd be an expert, I wouldn't ask here so I might be wrong :)

Comment: Defining something means nothing. You're not `returning it` to the caller and that is why for caller it is undefined. You can define a whole encyclopedia in a function but if you don't properly send it back to the caller (or make it global) it is out of scope for the caller.

Comment: Yes, because I am returning it if it is the last loop of each which is just the below line.

Comment: Whatever you're returning is returning a value to function from your loop closure. That value still remains in your function. You still have to return it from here `validate_email_extensions`. The returns that are there currently are only from your loop to `validate_email_extensions` and *not* from `validate_email_extensions` to `save_form`

Comment: I think I get the idea. I did it this way to make sure that I will send it after loop completed. But as you say, I am returning a value from loop to function, not from function to caller.

Comment: Yeah after 50 revisions haha :)

Comment: I am a (re)Visioner :) Sorry for revisions by the way. Thanks for help.